# Split a file name from a path in C

Tags: c

I am new to C but skilled in python. I am looking for a functional equivalent of the string.split("/")[-1] function in C. So far I have been able to make a character array that has my whole path. I want to split that string so I only have the file name. Below I have included a sample

```
char input_file_path [1024]
strcpy(input_file_path, "/this/is/my/file/path.txt")
```

I want some function that will take input_file_path and just split out the path.txt from it. Thanks!

Comment: I would avoid a method like `string.split("/")[-1]` because the directory separator may not be `"/"`

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for [`basename(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/basename/):

> The **`basename()`** function returns the last component from the pathname
>        pointed to by *path*, deleting any trailing '`/`' characters.

Example:

```
#include <libgen.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char path[] = "/this/is/my/file/path.txt";
    char *file = basename(path);
    printf("%s\n", file);
    return 0;
}
```

Build & run:

```
$ make example && ./example
cc     example.c   -o example
path.txt
```

Comment: It should be noted that basename() is provided by POSIX, not C itself.

Comment: That's true.  If you're on windows, you might need something else.  OP has `/` characters in his path, though.  My man page says it's from X/Open, not POSIX.

Comment: I think you're using outdated man pages. The latest version of kernel.org's man pages (version 3.53) lists it as "POSIX.1-2001". It's also in the POSIX Programmer's Manual: http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/3posix/basename/

Comment: That's Linux, I'm on a Mac.  Even the Linux man page says there are two versions.

Comment: Both do the same thing. The GNU version just fixes a bug in the POSIX version.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok

Check here. This is also a good reference for C and C++ code.

Comment: or better yet, strtok_r

Answer (score 0):

Try `strtok()`.

Look it up with the command `man strtok`. The `man` pages are a great guide to learn C without having to exit the safety of your command line.

Comment: There is no good reason to use strtok in preference to the much improved strtok_r.

Comment: True. Both ways, the OP should still learn to use the `man` pages since they are a very useful tool while programming in C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `basename` on Posix you can also use [splitpath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/splitpath-wsplitpath?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-160) on Windows to support multiple platforms conditionally.