# How do I append text to the name of the file from a fullpath (string) in C?

Tags: c

How do I append text to the name of the file from a fullpath (string) in C?

For example:

```
"/home/erikas/myfile.txt" would become "/home/erikas/myfile-generated.txt"
"/home/erikas/myfile" would become "/home/erikas/myfile-generated"
"/my.directory/my.super.file.txt" would become "/my.directory/my.super.file-generated.txt"
```

It just feels like I am trying to re-invent a wheel. Is there any simple solutions to this problem? A function?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970103/split-a-file-name-from-a-path-in-c

Comment: You have a classic path-splitting case where you need to first determine if the `filename` contains a path component at all (e.g. is there a `'/'` character). If so, you can use `strrchr` and `'/'` to get a pointer to the last `'/'` and isolate the filename. Then the problem switches to "Do I have an extension?". Same thing regarding the `'.'` (with sanity checks to protect 'dot/hidden' files (e.g. `.bashrc`)). If there is a `'.'` and it is separating `name.ext`, you have a pointer to `'.'` which you can isolate and save `.ext`, append your string and put things back together.

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180293/how-to-extract-filename-from-path

Comment: So, what's the rule for what needs changing?  Add `-generated` before the last dot of the last component of the pathname, or append it if there is no dot in the filename component?  What should happen with `/home/erikas/old.file.name`?  Presumably `/home/erikas/old.file-generated.name`?

Answer (score 1):

I've just managed to create my own solution for this.

Note that this code snippet will fail on *full path* like "myfile.txt" or "/home/my.user/", but in my case I used GTK to select file, so no issues to me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libgen.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#define SEPARATOR '\\'
#else
#define SEPARATOR '/'
#endif

#define GENERATED_APPEND_TEXT "-generated"

char *generate_output_fpath(char* fpath) {
    int last_separator_index = (int) (strrchr(fpath, SEPARATOR) - fpath);
    int last_dot_index = (int) (strrchr(fpath, '.') - fpath);

    char *new_fpath = malloc(strlen(fpath) + strlen(GENERATED_APPEND_TEXT) + 1); // +1 for \0

    if(new_fpath == NULL){
        return NULL; // malloc failed to allocate memory
    }

    // if dot does not exist or dot is before the last separator - file has no extension:
    if ( !last_dot_index || last_dot_index < last_separator_index) {
        new_fpath[0] = '\0'; //ensure it is empty
        strcat(new_fpath, fpath);
        strcat(new_fpath, GENERATED_APPEND_TEXT);
        return new_fpath;
    }

    int fpath_length = strlen(fpath);
    int append_text_length = strlen(GENERATED_APPEND_TEXT);

    int i = 0;
    int ii = 0;
    for (; i < last_dot_index; i++) {
        new_fpath[i] = fpath[i];
    }
    // We copied everything until dot. Now append:
    for (; ii < append_text_length; ii++) {
        new_fpath[i + ii] = GENERATED_APPEND_TEXT[ii];
    }
    // Now append extension with dot:
    for (; i < fpath_length; i++) {
        new_fpath[i + ii] = fpath[i];
    }
    return new_fpath;
}
```

Result:

```
"/home/erikas/myfile.txt" would become "/home/erikas/myfile-generated.txt"
"/home/erikas/myfile" would become "/home/erikas/myfile-generated"
```

Note that full example can be seen/tested here: [onlinegdb.com/HyPyfTvw7](http://onlinegdb.com/HyPyfTvw7)

Any tips regarding code optimization are welcome!

Comment: You should check that the memory allocation succeeds before using the allocated memory.  You should probably simply return NULL if the allocation fails, and the calling code should check that NULL was not returned.  Alternatively, you can print an appropriate error message and exit.  Whether that's a good idea depends on the context in which it is used.  If you're writing a command line program, it maybe OK; it's what I'd do, usually.  If you're writing a GUI program, it probably isn't appropriate for multiple reasons and simply returning NULL is better.

Comment: Also, I don't think your code yet handles the case of `/home/some.user/plain_file`; it will add `-generated` after the `.` in the path, which is not what you said you want.  The fix for that is easy; use `int last_dot_index = (int) (strrchr(&fpath[last_separator_index], '.') - fpath);`.  You might also need to be careful about trailing slashes (`/home/erikas/`) and plain file names `erikas_file`.  Both could give your code problems.

Comment: Updated to check if malloc did not fail. Also - this works perfectly fine - https://onlinegdb.com/HyPyfTvw7

Comment: Also I am using GTK to select file, so I am fool-proof that it won't be like "myfile.txt" or "/home/some.user/". Thanks anyway - I will mention this.

Comment: I misread (didn't read) the `|| last_dot_index < last_separator_index` part of the test — you're right, that handles the "last dot before last slash" condition (unless there is a trailing slash, but that's an exceptional problem anyway).  My apologies for that mistake.  There was no way for me to know that you're using GTK to get the original file name and hence can only get absolute names that don't have a trailing slash — though worrying about the trailing slash is something of a stretch at best.  (Even saying "I'm using GTK" wouldn't have told me that you'd get clean names.)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest two handy functions : basename and dirname instead